# Marker on map v2 disappear after orientation change

Tags: android, google-maps, screen-orientation

the markers I put on the map v2 with onMapclick disappear if the orientation changes, how can i make them reappear? Thank you!

```
    protected void addNewMarker(String title, String details, String nature, LatLng loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    count++;
    saveMarker.add(loc);
    saveTitle.add(title);
    saveDetails.add(details);
    saveNature.add(nature);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(loc)
    .title(title)
    .snippet(details+"\n"+nature));

    updatePolyLine(loc);


}
```

Comment: try to add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" to your  Activity's config in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `saveXxxxx` variables are `ArrayList<LatLng>` and `ArrayList<String>`, you can save them using

- [`Bundle.putStringArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putStringArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) and
- [`Bundle.putParcelableArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29)

inside overriden `onSaveInstanceState` and retrieve in `onCreate` using

- [`Bundle.getStringArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getStringArrayList%28java.lang.String%29) and
- [`Bundle.getParcelableArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String%29).

After recreating these lists, you have to create `Marker`s again using `GoogleMap.addMarker`.

Read more about [how to recreate `Activity` state here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState).